# Doctrine 2 Many to Many with join table, mapping?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, mapping, associations

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to map my three entities together. I have a "HouseType", a "Resource" and a HouseType can have multiple Resources (with an integer indicating how many of that resource they have). So I have three tables, the house_type, resource and house_type_resource (with house_type_id, resource_id, and num).

I can't figure out what type of association mapping I should do. I'm reading this page: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html but I don't see one that's like mine, where I have a third entity to represent the join table, because it has a specific property that needs to be included (the num).  It's sort of like the "Many-To-Many, Unidirectional" but I need that third Entity mapped in there. I see the note at the end about doing an Association class but I don't see any more info on that.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start adding extra columns, Doctrine stops treating it as a pure many-to-many relationship because there is extra data, and this data should be managed with an entity. You should create a new entity called `HouseTypeResource`, then create one-to-many relationships with this inside your `HouseType` and `Resource` entities.

Comment: Right, I know I need the third entity, I just can't figure out the mapping for it to the other two.